# Integrating SQLite with Qt Quick

Tags: sqlite, qml, qt-quick

I’m trying to include a SQLite database with QT Quick but I can’t find any examples. I just want to be able to access items from a database. Does anyone know of any example programs I can play with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could take [QSqlQueryModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqlquerymodel.html) for example, or any other SQL model and add it to the QML context and use it in the ListView for example.

### Create a model

Define the role names that will be used by delegates to access data by role in QtQuick components  (`data` method is bit naive as there is no kind of error checking):

```
class SqlQueryModel: public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QHash<int,QByteArray> *hash;
public:
    explicit SqlQueryModel(QObject * parent) : QSqlQueryModel(parent)
    {
        hash = new QHash<int,QByteArray>;
        hash->insert(Qt::UserRole,      QByteArray("someRoleName"));
        hash->insert(Qt::UserRole + 1,  QByteArray("otherRoleName"));
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
       if(role < Qt::UserRole) {
          return QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
       }
       QSqlRecord r = record(index.row());
       return r.value(QString(hash->value(role))).toString();
    }
    inline RoleNameHash roleNames() const { return *hash; }
};
```

### Add it to the QML

Create an instance of newly defined model class and add it to the QML context

```
view = new QQuickView();

QSqlQueryModel *someSqlModel = new SqlQueryModel(this);
someSqlModel->setQuery("SELECT someRoleName, otherRoleName FROM some_table");

QQmlContext *context = view->rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("someSqlModel", someSqlModel);

view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///MainView.qml"));
view->show();
```

### Bind the model to the QML View

Bind your model to the ListViews `model` property and use previously defined role names to access the data in the delegate.

```
ListView {
    id: someListView
    model: someSqlModel
    delegate: Text {
        anchors.fill: parent
        text: someRoleName
    }
}
```

---

### Some example links:

[How to use a QSqlQueryModel in QML](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_use_a_QSqlQueryModel_in_QML)

[QML and QSqlTableModel](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QML_and_QSqlTableModel)

Comment: You don't have any instance of "SqlQueryModel" in your code. What's the point of declaring the class SqlQueryModel?

Comment: @ondrejandrej It was a typo, I've fixed it, thanks for noticing. Using `QSqlQueryModel` made defining `SqlQueryModel` pointless and the example probably would not work since QML wouldn't find the `someRoleName` role.

Answer (score 7):

rebus' answer is a great start, but it me left wondering how to connect to an existing (SQLite) database.

So here's a complete example for Qt 5.x, no prerequisites needed.

Notice that the code avoids the role name hashtable lookup in SqlModel.data() and all superfluous heap allocations.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QHash>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>

QSqlError initDb()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    // Open database file. The driver creates a new file if it doesn't exist yet.
    db.setDatabaseName("mylibrary.sqlite");
    if (!db.open())
        return db.lastError();

    QStringList tables = db.tables();
    if (tables.contains("books", Qt::CaseInsensitive)) {
        // DB has already been populated
        return QSqlError();
    }

    QSqlQuery query;
    if (!query.exec(QLatin1String("create table books(title varchar, author varchar)")))
        return query.lastError();
    if (!query.prepare(QLatin1String("insert into books(title, author) values(?, ?)")))
        return query.lastError();

    auto addBook = [&] (const QString& title, const QString& author) {
        query.addBindValue(title);
        query.addBindValue(author);
        query.exec();
    };

    addBook("Mademoiselle de Maupin", "T. Gautier");
    addBook("Der Nachsommer", "A. Stifter");
    addBook("L'Education sentimentale", "G. Flaubert");
    addBook("Voyna i mir", "L. Tolstoy");
    addBook("Mysterier", "K. Hamsun");
    addBook("The Sound and the Fury", "W. Faulkner");
    addBook("Tender is the Night", "F. Scott Fitzgerald");

    return QSqlError();
}

class SqlModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SqlModel(QObject* parent = 0)
        : QSqlQueryModel(parent)
    {
        roleNamesHash.insert(Qt::UserRole,      QByteArray("title"));
        roleNamesHash.insert(Qt::UserRole + 1,  QByteArray("author"));
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
    {
        if(role < Qt::UserRole)
            return QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);

        QSqlRecord r = record(index.row());
        return r.value(role - Qt::UserRole);
    }

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const { return roleNamesHash; }

private:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNamesHash;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    auto err = initDb();
    if (err.type() != QSqlError::NoError) {
        qCritical() << err.text();
        return 1;
    }

    SqlModel sqlModel;
    sqlModel.setQuery("SELECT title, author FROM books");

    QQuickView view;
    QQmlContext *context = view.rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("sqlModel", &sqlModel);
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:///main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Item {
    width: 500
    height: 300

    ListView {
        anchors { fill: parent; margins: 20 }
        model: sqlModel
        delegate: Text {
            text: author + ' - ' + title
        }
    }
}
```

**resources.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**minimal-qml-sql-app.pro**

```
CONFIG += c++11

QT += qml \
      quick \
      sql
SOURCES += main.cpp
OTHER_FILES += main.qml
RESOURCES += resources.qrc
```

Comment: I had to remove Q_OBJECT and #include "main.moc". Don't know if these are important, but it won't build unless I remove them.

Answer (score 4):

In Qt 5.3, there's an example in

> Examples/Qt-5.3/quick/controls/calendar

One interesting note compared to rebus and Kay's answers: The calendar example exposes the SqlModel using

> qmlRegisterType()

This allows for a more declarative programming style: there's no need to instantiate an SqlModel in main.cpp. Instead, you declare it in your qml.

Comment: Great point of entry to learn the SQL integration using QML in a proper way. So many thanks

Comment: This is a good point about QML integration, but unfortunately the model in that example doesn't really behave like a model, because `Calendar` already has its own model (for days in the month). Instead, it just gets a list of events (a `QList<QObject*>` model) for a particular day. It was recently changed to simply be a `QObject` because of this fact: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/145253/